# retrieving integer values from SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

in this app I`m trying give different welcome message to each type of users
so here is the code in my DB helper class

```
public int loginCheck(String a,String b)
{
   int ty;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users where user_name = '"+a+"'AND user_password = '"+b+"';", null);
    ty= c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("user_type"));

    if (c.getCount()<=0)
    {
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return 2;
    }
    else
    c.close();       
    db.close();       
    return ty;


}
```

it should check the user type whether 0 or 1 ,, and according to the return value the welcome message appears,what i got that this retrieves the number of the column , it retrieves 6 and "user_type" is the sixth column

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: Not my downvote, but _please_ consider using prepared statements.  This would already solve a lot of the problems you are having.

Comment: You forgot a space in your query between your paramater `a` and `AND`. Furthermore you get an int from your cursor before you've even checked if your cursor is empty. Aside from that your `else` doesn't have braces, meaning your database will be closed twice if your cursor is empty. But in that scenario your application is probably already crashed

Comment: thanks for your comment @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: thanks for your comment @0xDEADC0DE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move to the first row first:

```
public int loginCheck(String a,String b) {
    int ty;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users where user_name = '"+a+"' AND user_password = '"+b+"';", null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        ty = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("user_type"));
    } else {
        ty = 2;
    }

    c.close();
    db.close();

    return ty;
}
```

[`cursor.moveToFirst`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()) will return false if it wasn't able to move to the first row (e.g. the cursor is empty), so no need for the c.getCount() check

=====

The Android way of doing this (not using `rawQuery` unless have to):

```
public int loginCheck(String a,String b) {
    int ty;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query("users", new String[] { "user_type" }, "user_name = ? AND user_password = ?", new String[] {a, user_password}, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        ty = c.getInt(0);
    } else {
        ty = 2;
    }

    c.close();
    db.close();

    return ty;
}
```

Comment: The Android way would be using [longForQuery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).